# How to configure a SVC Web Service MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory disabling anonymous users

Tags: web-services, authentication, rest

I developed a SVC on SharePoint 2010 that uses MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory. Inside of some methods I need to know who's the caller.

I find that I have two way to get it:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name (for basic)
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name (for windows auth)
```

This works great with IE. If I try to access the web service from Firefox or PowerPivot the values are null and so I cannot find out who is the caller.

I tried tons of web.config but the fact is:

- If I disable Anonymous auth, SharePoint throws an Exception
- If I disable Windows auth, SharePoint throws an Exception

I also tried to put some "denies" on Anonymous users without any result.

As is I have no web.config so the configuration of MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory.

This is the interface of my service:

```
[ServiceContract]
 public interface IGetListData
 {
     [OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
     System.IO.Stream GetData(string SiteUrl, string ListName, string ViewName);
 }
```

Is there any way to tag the method as "only basic auth"? I tried with [HttpBasic...] without any result.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deploying the service under the TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS folder the impersonation has work correctly.

The Service now uses the factory config to define endpoints and so on, without custom configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed the .SVC in the SharePoint ISAPI folder then the web service should be running "in context" and you should be able to get the current user from the SPContext.Current.Web.User object.

Comment: SPContext.Current didn't contain a User object.. The unique way is use SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser that is null.. Do I need other reference / installation steps?

Comment: Is your web service endpoint under "_layouts" or "_vti_bin"? It makes a difference in terms of the SPContext object.

Comment: is deployed under the _vti_bin folder

Comment: Well... it works for me :)